# LabVIEW - Variant to Database Variant

Tags: database, labview, variant

I've created a save VI that can save several different classes to database using dynamic dispatch. Each class has a different type defined cluster that I want to be saved. I'm trying to convert each cluster into a database variant, so they all output the same thing that I can save to the database. I can get them to create an array of variants, which I thought would work, but it doesn't, presumably because these are LabVIEW variants, not database variants.

How can I convert each of these clusters into the same type to use in my generic save to database VI?

The clusters all contain different numbers and types of variables, including strings, numerics, and even other clusters.

Thank you in advance for any answers comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mikhail N Zakharov pointed out, you can convert a cluster to a single variant, rather than an array of variants. This single variant can then be saved in the database normally.

My problem was trying to go through the type the database read gives you; an array of variants, assuming reading from and writing to the database could be achieved with the same types.

Comment: Note that this is a LabVIEW variant and will be stored as a BLOB field in one record of the database. As such, you won't be able to perform SQL queries on the individual fields contained in the LabVIEW variant.

Comment: Thanks @PhilBrooks for making me think to check this, but you're wrong. The data is stored correctly, as if I had passed the save tool the original cluster. I'm working in LabVIEW 2014, it may have behaved differently in previous versions, for instance Flatten Cluster defaulting to true instead of false.

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide examples. Specifically,

1. What database toolkit are you using? What are this DB toolkit VIs
   accepting? Post working code sample.
2. You control what to output from your virtual serialization method. Can you be more specific as to why you can not output a single variant, but have to output an array instead? Can you post a relevant part of the code?
3. what do you mean by "would work, but it doesn't, presumably because ...". Please, provide a code sample that does not work and an error message it produces...

Comment: 1. I'm using National Instruments "Database Connectivity Toolkit". Normally I write a whole cluster (representing one row, or occasionally part of a row) to the insert or update VIs, but it also works with arrays and single values.

Comment: 2. I've made the read operation generic by reading to a database variant array, which I then pass to a dynamic dispatch VI to convert to the right cluster for each class. I'm trying to do the inverse here, so I tried using the same types, also, LabVIEW converts a cluster to a 1D array of variants, and I haven't looked into weather it can do it any other way.

Comment: 3. I thought it would work because writing an array of variants seemed like a reasonable alternative to a cluster, as it's what you get when you convert a cluster to a variant.
I'll add code to these comments once I take screen shots of them.

Comment: 2. I've just found out you can convert a cluster to a single variant, and the DCT lets you save that with no problem (I was using the variant to data, and telling it to convert to an array of variants, instead of simply using the data to variant.). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to the solution.